# I'm confused about using Share and NTFS permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions, file-sharing

I've been doing research into Share and NTFS permissions (i like to do research into things IT related when i have a quiet moment at my job), i know both serve the same purpose and that many companies utilise both in unison however i can't seem to get my head round why this is common practice

I know this can be slightly subjective but i can't seem to find anywhere online that is giving me the information that i'm looking for

If Share and NTFS permissions both restrict permissions for Files and Folders the same way why would you use both together; i'm obviously missing something regarding permissions. Could someone help me out here

Comment: I can't find a good reference, but perhaps share rights are _older_ than NTFS ACL feature? I have vague memories of the former being supported by WIndows 98 when in 'domain' mode.

Answer (score 2):

### "Share" and NTFS Permissions: Mostly Redundant For a Reason

> I've been doing research into Share and NTFS permissions...i know both serve the same purpose...

The "Share" permissions you're referring to are part of the Microsoft SMB protocol.  [SMB permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753731(v=ws.11).aspx) apply to any data served via the SMB protocol. **This includes data stored on filesystems that don't have their own access-control mechanism, such as FAT32.** Before NTFS was widely used, SMB permissions were often the only control a system administrator had over user access to shared data.

> ...and that many companies utilise both in unison however i can't seem to get my head round why this is common practice.

By now you're probably realizing the reason this is "common practice" is because admins don't have a choice in the matter.  When data stored on an NTFS filesystem is shared via SMB, *both* permission schemes are operational. You can't simply ignore one of them and have things go well.

#### Let's Ignore Them Anyway

Often you'll find that Admins effectively bypass the SMB permissions by granting the `Everyone` identity Full Control in the Share Permissions dialog, then rely solely on the NTFS permissions to manage user access to data.  In the majority of environments the vastly superior NTFS permissions are on the table so this works without unwanted consequences.

#### Can SMB+NTFS Permissions Work Together?

I have run across an interesting use case where SMB and NTFS permissions can work together to accomplish something that's not feasible with only one of the schemes. Basically the goal is to prevent users that have NTFS Full Control permissions from using them to grant themselves access to files/folders they would otherwise be able to modify. For more information and background on why this can't be done with NTFS permissions alone, see this [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1235806/213131).

Answer (score 1):

Share- and NTFS Permissions offer a very different set of options.

Share permissions, for the most part, are limit to Read/Change (Modify/Write)/Full Control. With just these three levels you only get some very basic permission setup. You can select to allow or deny each but you're limited in what you can do.

NTFS Permissions offer the same and more. You can set pretty granular permission and you get some additional features like setting SACLs ([NTFS Access Control Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872(v=vs.85).aspx). See below for an example of additional permissions that are available.

Another important thing is that NTFS permissions are "stronger" than share permissions. While you might have "Full Control" on a share NTFS permissions might limit it in various ways (See also [Share and NTFS Permissions on a File Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178(v=ws.11).aspx)).

[image: NTFS permission details]