# Export UNC path NTFS permissions to CSV file

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-permissions, unc

I need to export UNC path NTFS permissions on a Windows Server 2008, the only way I found possible so far is "wmic /node:rhea share get name,path" this will provide me with the share and local path but I also need NTFS permissions included in the report.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could try the PowerShell commands of [Get-SmbShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbshare?view=windowsserver2019-ps) and [Get-SmbShareAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbshareaccess?view=windowsserver2019-ps). An example code would be : `$Results = Get-SmbShare | Get-SmbShareAccess` and
`$Results | Export-CSV -Path "<pathToCSVFile>"`. Let me know if it helps. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, see [NTFS vs Share permissions](https://superuser.com/a/1236326/673426)

- For **NTFS** permissions, you can use `Get-Acl` which should work in that version of powershell:

```
# get NTFS permissions for one shared folder
(Get-Acl "C:\path\to\share").Access | Export-Csv "C:\temp\report.csv" -N

# or to get it for all shares, you can query WMI to get the list of shares:
Foreach ($share in (Get-WmiObject win32_share | where {$_.path})) { 
  # separate the list of permissions with the path of each share
  $share.Path | Out-File Aappend "c:\temp\report.csv"
  ($share.path | Get-Acl).access | ConvertTo-Csv -N | Out-File -Append "c:\temp\report.csv"
}
```

- For the **Share** paths and permissions, you can export that from the registry under:

```
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares\Security
```